# Chilkat Could not Load Assembly

Tags: chilkat

Trying to use Chilkat in .NET framework 4.5.  I don't want to use the latest version, I need to continue using version 9.5.0.56.

Getting this error message:

```
---------------------------
Could not load file or assembly 'ChilkatDotNet45.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
---------------------------
```

It works on MY computer, but NOT on any other computers, even with the DLL placed in the same directory as my program. I have read [this page](http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/6262/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-chilkatdotnetdll-or-one-of-its-dependencies-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) and [this page](http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/1430/visual-studio-2012-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-chilkatdotnet45dll) with no success.

Tried compiling with Visual Studio 2019 and 2013 using .NET framework 4.5.2 and 4.5. Tried x86 and x64 and Any CPU prefer 32-bit. Installed VC++ 2013 (it was already installed but did a repair). I added the reference path where my Chilkat DLL is located. Tried registering with regsvr32 but it failed.

Using Windows 10.  Any ideas here?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a licensing problem.  Once I repurchased and got a new unlock code, the issue went away.